# Compare two tables and extract the columns similar to both

Tags: python, member, intersect

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDPCj.png)Hi I have two data matrix, one is A and the other is B. I want to compare the first row of A to that of B and if a match is found in B, then the whole column(s) in B should be extracted. In the attached file, under A, 11, 12, 13 and 14 can also be found in B. In this case all the values under 11, 12, 13 and 14 in B are extracted into C. In other words, A is a row vector and I want to compare it to the first row of B.

I have the following Matlab expression that works and I would like to translate it to python:

```
C = B(:,ismember(B(1,:),A))
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO. Please show any effort and provide some code so we can help you. At the very least show the tables and expect results in a proper way.

Comment: C = B(:,ismember(B(1,:),A))   I have this which works in matlab

Comment: OK, can you provide two or more lines of A and B?

Comment: Did you use numpy or list of lists to create the matrix?

Comment: I am new to python. I tried attaching an image to show but it did not work. I used list of lists to create a matrix. A is a row vector and B is a 4 by 3 matrix. Some of the first row of A can be found in the first row of B. I want to compare the first row of A to that of B

Comment: Search for numpy to create matrix, it's faster. I will try to provide an answer with list of lists anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
A = [[11, 12, 13, 14]]

B = [[11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16],
     [2, 1.1, 1.1, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5],
     [2, 1.1, 1.1, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5],
     [2, 1.1, 1.1, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5],
     [2, 1.1, 1.1, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5]]

# Get difference between two lists.
diffs = set(A[0]).symmetric_difference(set(B[0]))


# Get the members index with list comprehension.
indexes = [B[0].index(diff) for diff in diffs]

# Copy B into C. Use copy() otherwise only the reference will be copied.
C = B.copy()

# Delete the columns of C
# This is slow but more readable since you are a beginner in python.
for row in C: 
    for index in indexes:
        del row[index]

    print(row)
```

Which Yields:

```
[11, 12, 13, 14]
[2, 1.1, 1.1, 1.3]
[2, 1.1, 1.1, 1.3]
[2, 1.1, 1.1, 1.3]
[2, 1.1, 1.1, 1.3]
```

This code is far from optimized, it's just to show you the several steps to achieve the result.

Comment: @Python1 Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks @Raphael, I have also attached an image of how it should be. I appreciate it.

Comment: @Python1 Take a look now. If a have time I will provide a solution with numpy.